# Vaadin grid - gridpro ComboBox Editor

Tags: grid, vaadin

Grid Pro features three recommended built-in editors: Text Field, Checkbox, and Select.
Ho can you manage a list with key and value properties?
For example:
[Country list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jthf.png)

I'm unable to show **country name** in the select value and save the **id** in the database record.
I usually rely on ComboBox when I manage a list with key and value.
Combobox is not present in the list of built-in editors.
Do you suggest to write your own editor?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a `Country` class with the properties `id` and `name`. And a `Person` class with a `country` property. You display a `GridPro<Person>`.

You can make a `Select` editor and define it's itemLabelGenerator (or renderer, if you want to show a flag or something) to show `Country::getName`. **

The saving to the database should be handled by the annotations on the relation. Usually using JPA, there would be a @ManyToOne relation between Person and Country, and save the country-FK (id, specified using @Id) in the person table.

** I don't use Grid Pro, but upon inspection of the code I can see that by using `gridPro.addEditColumn(Person::getCountry).select(Person::setCountry, countriesList)` you cannot specify the itemLabelGenerator/renderer.
However, you could prepare your own `Select` component and use the `EditColumnConfigurator::custom`method.

```
Select<Country> countryEditorComponent = new Select<>();
countryEditorComponent.setItems(countriesList);
countryEditorComponent.setItemLabelGenerator(country -> country.getName());
gridPro.addEditColumn(Person::getCountry).custom(countryEditorComponent , Person::setCountry).setHeader("Country");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works :-)
After some tests, eventually, I used ComboBox as a parameter in the custom method.
The new Combobox implements a search (contains) that is very attractive for the users.